# How to apply gradient for image in image view in android

Tags: android

Can anybody tell is it possible to give gradient for image in image view in android if yes can anybody tell how to do

Any help would be appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your layout:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/photo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/my_picture"
    android:src="@drawable/gradient_shape" />
```

and make `res/drawable/gradient_shape.xml` file as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
            android:startColor="#00FFFFFF"
            android:endColor="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:type="linear" />
</shape>
```